# Get a list of Font Awesome icons

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, font-awesome

I would like to show all the Font-Awesome icons, where can I get a list of them? It should be in JSON, XML, or something similar

Answer (score 7):

Asked them on twitter,
answer:

> src/icons.yml in the repo.

Answer (score 6):

A dirty/hacky solution is to visit the [icons page](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/icons/), open your browser inspector and execute the following javascript:

```
    Array.prototype.getUnique = function(){
       var u = {}, a = [];
       for(var i = 0, l = this.length; i < l; ++i){
          if(u.hasOwnProperty(this[i])) {
             continue;
          }
          a.push(this[i]);
          u[this[i]] = 1;
       }
       return a;
    }
    var classes = [];
    $('#icons i').each(function(){
        $($(this).attr('class').split(' ')).each(function() { 
            if (this.length>0 && $.inArray(this.valueOf(), classes) === -1 && this.valueOf() !== "fa" ) {
                classes.push("'"+this.valueOf()+"'");
            }    
        });
    });
    document.body.innerHTML = classes.getUnique();
```

It will output a list of all the icon classes where you can simply copy-paste it anywhere you like.

In PHP for example, you could then do:

```
$font_awesome_class_list = array( Paste the list here );
echo json_encode( $font_awesome_class_list );
```

The advantage of this, is that you instantly get all the icon classes. However, you have to manually edit your code.

Comment: This was working for me, thanks man!

Answer (score 5):

```
    [
    {"c": "fa-500px", "l": "500px"},
    {"c": "fa-adjust", "l": "Adjust"},
    {"c": "fa-adn", "l": "Adn"},
    {"c": "fa-align-center", "l": "Align center"},
    {"c": "fa-align-justify", "l": "Align justify"},
    {"c": "fa-align-left", "l": "Align left"},
    {"c": "fa-align-right", "l": "Align right"},
    {"c": "fa-amazon", "l": "Amazon"},
    {"c": "fa-ambulance", "l": "Ambulance"},
    {"c": "fa-anchor", "l": "Anchor"},
    {"c": "fa-android", "l": "Android"},
    {"c": "fa-angellist", "l": "Angellist"},
    {"c": "fa-angle-double-down", "l": "Angle double down"},
    {"c": "fa-angle-double-left", "l": "Angle double left"},
    {"c": "fa-angle-double-right", "l": "Angle double right"},
    {"c": "fa-angle-double-up", "l": "Angle double up"},
    {"c": "fa-angle-down", "l": "Angle down"},
    {"c": "fa-angle-left", "l": "Angle left"},
    {"c": "fa-angle-right", "l": "Angle right"},
    {"c": "fa-angle-up", "l": "Angle up"},
    {"c": "fa-apple", "l": "Apple"},
    {"c": "fa-archive", "l": "Archive"},
    {"c": "fa-area-chart", "l": "Area chart"},
    {"c": "fa-arrow-circle-down", "l": "Arrow circle down"},
    {"c": "fa-arrow-circle-left", "l": "Arrow circle left"},
    {"c": "fa-arrow-circle-o-down", "l": "Arrow circle o down"},
    {"c": "fa-arrow-circle-o-left", "l": "Arrow circle o left"},
    {"c": "fa-arrow-circle-o-right", "l": "Arrow circle o right"},
    {"c": "fa-arrow-circle-o-up", "l": "Arrow circle o up"},
    {"c": "fa-arrow-circle-right", "l": "Arrow circle right"},
    {"c": "fa-arrow-circle-up", "l": "Arrow circle up"},
    {"c": "fa-arrow-down", "l": "Arrow down"},
    {"c": "fa-arrow-left", "l": "Arrow left"},
    {"c": "fa-arrow-right", "l": "Arrow right"},
    {"c": "fa-arrow-up", "l": "Arrow up"},
    {"c": "fa-arrows", "l": "Arrows"},
    {"c": "fa-arrows-alt", "l": "Arrows alt"},
    {"c": "fa-arrows-h", "l": "Arrows h"},
    {"c": "fa-arrows-v", "l": "Arrows v"},
    {"c": "fa-asterisk", "l": "Asterisk"},
    {"c": "fa-at", "l": "At"},
    {"c": "fa-backward", "l": "Backward"},
    {"c": "fa-balance-scale", "l": "Balance scale"},
    {"c": "fa-ban", "l": "Ban"},
    {"c": "fa-bar-chart", "l": "Bar chart"},
    {"c": "fa-barcode", "l": "Barcode"},
    {"c": "fa-bars", "l": "Bars"},
    {"c": "fa-battery-empty", "l": "Battery empty"},
    {"c": "fa-battery-full", "l": "Battery full"},
    {"c": "fa-battery-half", "l": "Battery half"},
    {"c": "fa-battery-quarter", "l": "Battery quarter"},
    {"c": "fa-battery-three-quarters", "l": "Battery three quarters"},
    {"c": "fa-bed", "l": "Bed"},
    {"c": "fa-beer", "l": "Beer"},
    {"c": "fa-behance", "l": "Behance"},
    {"c": "fa-behance-square", "l": "Behance square"},
    {"c": "fa-bell", "l": "Bell"},
    {"c": "fa-bell-o", "l": "Bell o"},
    {"c": "fa-bell-slash", "l": "Bell slash"},
    {"c": "fa-bell-slash-o", "l": "Bell slash o"},
    {"c": "fa-bicycle", "l": "Bicycle"},
    {"c": "fa-binoculars", "l": "Binoculars"},
    {"c": "fa-birthday-cake", "l": "Birthday cake"},
    {"c": "fa-bitbucket", "l": "Bitbucket"},
    {"c": "fa-bitbucket-square", "l": "Bitbucket square"},
    {"c": "fa-black-tie", "l": "Black tie"},
    {"c": "fa-bold", "l": "Bold"},
    {"c": "fa-bolt", "l": "Bolt"},
    {"c": "fa-bomb", "l": "Bomb"},
    {"c": "fa-book", "l": "Book"},
    {"c": "fa-bookmark", "l": "Bookmark"},
    {"c": "fa-bookmark-o", "l": "Bookmark o"},
    {"c": "fa-briefcase", "l": "Briefcase"},
    {"c": "fa-btc", "l": "Btc"},
    {"c": "fa-bug", "l": "Bug"},
    {"c": "fa-building", "l": "Building"},
    {"c": "fa-building-o", "l": "Building o"},
    {"c": "fa-bullhorn", "l": "Bullhorn"},
    {"c": "fa-bullseye", "l": "Bullseye"},
    {"c": "fa-bus", "l": "Bus"},
    {"c": "fa-buysellads", "l": "Buysellads"},
    {"c": "fa-calculator", "l": "Calculator"},
    {"c": "fa-calendar", "l": "Calendar"},
    {"c": "fa-calendar-check-o", "l": "Calendar check o"},
    {"c": "fa-calendar-minus-o", "l": "Calendar minus o"},
    {"c": "fa-calendar-o", "l": "Calendar o"},
    {"c": "fa-calendar-plus-o", "l": "Calendar plus o"},
    {"c": "fa-calendar-times-o", "l": "Calendar times o"},
    {"c": "fa-camera", "l": "Camera"},
    {"c": "fa-camera-retro", "l": "Camera retro"},
    {"c": "fa-car", "l": "Car"},
    {"c": "fa-caret-down", "l": "Caret down"},
    {"c": "fa-caret-left", "l": "Caret left"},
    {"c": "fa-caret-right", "l": "Caret right"},
    {"c": "fa-caret-square-o-down", "l": "Caret square o down"},
    {"c": "fa-caret-square-o-left", "l": "Caret square o left"},
    {"c": "fa-caret-square-o-right", "l": "Caret square o right"},
    {"c": "fa-caret-square-o-up", "l": "Caret square o up"},
    {"c": "fa-caret-up", "l": "Caret up"},
    {"c": "fa-cart-arrow-down", "l": "Cart arrow down"},
    {"c": "fa-cart-plus", "l": "Cart plus"},
    {"c": "fa-cc", "l": "Cc"},
    {"c": "fa-cc-amex", "l": "Cc amex"},
    {"c": "fa-cc-diners-club", "l": "Cc diners club"},
    {"c": "fa-cc-discover", "l": "Cc discover"},
    {"c": "fa-cc-jcb", "l": "Cc jcb"},
    {"c": "fa-cc-mastercard", "l": "Cc mastercard"},
    {"c": "fa-cc-paypal", "l": "Cc paypal"},
    {"c": "fa-cc-stripe", "l": "Cc stripe"},
    {"c": "fa-cc-visa", "l": "Cc visa"},
    {"c": "fa-certificate", "l": "Certificate"},
    {"c": "fa-chain-broken", "l": "Chain broken"},
    {"c": "fa-check", "l": "Check"},
    {"c": "fa-check-circle", "l": "Check circle"},
    {"c": "fa-check-circle-o", "l": "Check circle o"},
    {"c": "fa-check-square", "l": "Check square"},
    {"c": "fa-check-square-o", "l": "Check square o"},
    {"c": "fa-chevron-circle-down", "l": "Chevron circle down"},
    {"c": "fa-chevron-circle-left", "l": "Chevron circle left"},
    {"c": "fa-chevron-circle-right", "l": "Chevron circle right"},
    {"c": "fa-chevron-circle-up", "l": "Chevron circle up"},
    {"c": "fa-chevron-down", "l": "Chevron down"},
    {"c": "fa-chevron-left", "l": "Chevron left"},
    {"c": "fa-chevron-right", "l": "Chevron right"},
    {"c": "fa-chevron-up", "l": "Chevron up"},
    {"c": "fa-child", "l": "Child"},
    {"c": "fa-chrome", "l": "Chrome"},
    {"c": "fa-circle", "l": "Circle"},
    {"c": "fa-circle-o", "l": "Circle o"},
    {"c": "fa-circle-o-notch", "l": "Circle o notch"},
    {"c": "fa-circle-thin", "l": "Circle thin"},
    {"c": "fa-clipboard", "l": "Clipboard"},
    {"c": "fa-clock-o", "l": "Clock o"},
    {"c": "fa-clone", "l": "Clone"},
    {"c": "fa-cloud", "l": "Cloud"},
    {"c": "fa-cloud-download", "l": "Cloud download"},
    {"c": "fa-cloud-upload", "l": "Cloud upload"},
    {"c": "fa-code", "l": "Code"},
    {"c": "fa-code-fork", "l": "Code fork"},
    {"c": "fa-codepen", "l": "Codepen"},
    {"c": "fa-coffee", "l": "Coffee"},
    {"c": "fa-cog", "l": "Cog"},
    {"c": "fa-cogs", "l": "Cogs"},
    {"c": "fa-columns", "l": "Columns"},
    {"c": "fa-comment", "l": "Comment"},
    {"c": "fa-comment-o", "l": "Comment o"},
    {"c": "fa-commenting", "l": "Commenting"},
    {"c": "fa-commenting-o", "l": "Commenting o"},
    {"c": "fa-comments", "l": "Comments"},
    {"c": "fa-comments-o", "l": "Comments o"},
    {"c": "fa-compass", "l": "Compass"},
    {"c": "fa-compress", "l": "Compress"},
    {"c": "fa-connectdevelop", "l": "Connectdevelop"},
    {"c": "fa-contao", "l": "Contao"},
    {"c": "fa-copyright", "l": "Copyright"},
    {"c": "fa-creative-commons", "l": "Creative commons"},
    {"c": "fa-credit-card", "l": "Credit card"},
    {"c": "fa-crop", "l": "Crop"},
    {"c": "fa-crosshairs", "l": "Crosshairs"},
    {"c": "fa-css3", "l": "Css3"},
    {"c": "fa-cube", "l": "Cube"},
    {"c": "fa-cubes", "l": "Cubes"},
    {"c": "fa-cutlery", "l": "Cutlery"},
    {"c": "fa-dashcube", "l": "Dashcube"},
    {"c": "fa-database", "l": "Database"},
    {"c": "fa-delicious", "l": "Delicious"},
    {"c": "fa-desktop", "l": "Desktop"},
    {"c": "fa-deviantart", "l": "Deviantart"},
    {"c": "fa-diamond", "l": "Diamond"},
    {"c": "fa-digg", "l": "Digg"},
    {"c": "fa-dot-circle-o", "l": "Dot circle o"},
    {"c": "fa-download", "l": "Download"},
    {"c": "fa-dribbble", "l": "Dribbble"},
    {"c": "fa-dropbox", "l": "Dropbox"},
    {"c": "fa-drupal", "l": "Drupal"},
    {"c": "fa-eject", "l": "Eject"},
    {"c": "fa-ellipsis-h", "l": "Ellipsis h"},
    {"c": "fa-ellipsis-v", "l": "Ellipsis v"},
    {"c": "fa-empire", "l": "Empire"},
    {"c": "fa-envelope", "l": "Envelope"},
    {"c": "fa-envelope-o", "l": "Envelope o"},
    {"c": "fa-envelope-square", "l": "Envelope square"},
    {"c": "fa-eraser", "l": "Eraser"},
    {"c": "fa-eur", "l": "Eur"},
    {"c": "fa-exchange", "l": "Exchange"},
    {"c": "fa-exclamation", "l": "Exclamation"},
    {"c": "fa-exclamation-circle", "l": "Exclamation circle"},
    {"c": "fa-exclamation-triangle", "l": "Exclamation triangle"},
    {"c": "fa-expand", "l": "Expand"},
    {"c": "fa-expeditedssl", "l": "Expeditedssl"},
    {"c": "fa-external-link", "l": "External link"},
    {"c": "fa-external-link-square", "l": "External link square"},
    {"c": "fa-eye", "l": "Eye"},
    {"c": "fa-eye-slash", "l": "Eye slash"},
    {"c": "fa-eyedropper", "l": "Eyedropper"},
    {"c": "fa-facebook", "l": "Facebook"},
    {"c": "fa-facebook-official", "l": "Facebook official"},
    {"c": "fa-facebook-square", "l": "Facebook square"},
    {"c": "fa-fast-backward", "l": "Fast backward"},
    {"c": "fa-fast-forward", "l": "Fast forward"},
    {"c": "fa-fax", "l": "Fax"},
    {"c": "fa-female", "l": "Female"},
    {"c": "fa-fighter-jet", "l": "Fighter jet"},
    {"c": "fa-file", "l": "File"},
    {"c": "fa-file-archive-o", "l": "File archive o"},
    {"c": "fa-file-audio-o", "l": "File audio o"},
    {"c": "fa-file-code-o", "l": "File code o"},
    {"c": "fa-file-excel-o", "l": "File excel o"},
    {"c": "fa-file-image-o", "l": "File image o"},
    {"c": "fa-file-o", "l": "File o"},
    {"c": "fa-file-pdf-o", "l": "File pdf o"},
    {"c": "fa-file-powerpoint-o", "l": "File powerpoint o"},
    {"c": "fa-file-text", "l": "File text"},
    {"c": "fa-file-text-o", "l": "File text o"},
    {"c": "fa-file-video-o", "l": "File video o"},
    {"c": "fa-file-word-o", "l": "File word o"},
    {"c": "fa-files-o", "l": "Files o"},
    {"c": "fa-film", "l": "Film"},
    {"c": "fa-filter", "l": "Filter"},
    {"c": "fa-fire", "l": "Fire"},
    {"c": "fa-fire-extinguisher", "l": "Fire extinguisher"},
    {"c": "fa-firefox", "l": "Firefox"},
    {"c": "fa-flag", "l": "Flag"},
    {"c": "fa-flag-checkered", "l": "Flag checkered"},
    {"c": "fa-flag-o", "l": "Flag o"},
    {"c": "fa-flask", "l": "Flask"},
    {"c": "fa-flickr", "l": "Flickr"},
    {"c": "fa-floppy-o", "l": "Floppy o"},
    {"c": "fa-folder", "l": "Folder"},
    {"c": "fa-folder-o", "l": "Folder o"},
    {"c": "fa-folder-open", "l": "Folder open"},
    {"c": "fa-folder-open-o", "l": "Folder open o"},
    {"c": "fa-font", "l": "Font"},
    {"c": "fa-fonticons", "l": "Fonticons"},
    {"c": "fa-forumbee", "l": "Forumbee"},
    {"c": "fa-forward", "l": "Forward"},
    {"c": "fa-foursquare", "l": "Foursquare"},
    {"c": "fa-frown-o", "l": "Frown o"},
    {"c": "fa-futbol-o", "l": "Futbol o"},
    {"c": "fa-gamepad", "l": "Gamepad"},
    {"c": "fa-gavel", "l": "Gavel"},
    {"c": "fa-gbp", "l": "Gbp"},
    {"c": "fa-genderless", "l": "Genderless"},
    {"c": "fa-get-pocket", "l": "Get pocket"},
    {"c": "fa-gg", "l": "Gg"},
    {"c": "fa-gg-circle", "l": "Gg circle"},
    {"c": "fa-gift", "l": "Gift"},
    {"c": "fa-git", "l": "Git"},
    {"c": "fa-git-square", "l": "Git square"},
    {"c": "fa-github", "l": "Github"},
    {"c": "fa-github-alt", "l": "Github alt"},
    {"c": "fa-github-square", "l": "Github square"},
    {"c": "fa-glass", "l": "Glass"},
    {"c": "fa-globe", "l": "Globe"},
    {"c": "fa-google", "l": "Google"},
    {"c": "fa-google-plus", "l": "Google plus"},
    {"c": "fa-google-plus-square", "l": "Google plus square"},
    {"c": "fa-google-wallet", "l": "Google wallet"},
    {"c": "fa-graduation-cap", "l": "Graduation cap"},
    {"c": "fa-gratipay", "l": "Gratipay"},
    {"c": "fa-h-square", "l": "H square"},
    {"c": "fa-hacker-news", "l": "Hacker news"},
    {"c": "fa-hand-lizard-o", "l": "Hand lizard o"},
    {"c": "fa-hand-o-down", "l": "Hand o down"},
    {"c": "fa-hand-o-left", "l": "Hand o left"},
    {"c": "fa-hand-o-right", "l": "Hand o right"},
    {"c": "fa-hand-o-up", "l": "Hand o up"},
    {"c": "fa-hand-paper-o", "l": "Hand paper o"},
    {"c": "fa-hand-peace-o", "l": "Hand peace o"},
    {"c": "fa-hand-pointer-o", "l": "Hand pointer o"},
    {"c": "fa-hand-rock-o", "l": "Hand rock o"},
    {"c": "fa-hand-scissors-o", "l": "Hand scissors o"},
    {"c": "fa-hand-spock-o", "l": "Hand spock o"},
    {"c": "fa-hdd-o", "l": "Hdd o"},
    {"c": "fa-header", "l": "Header"},
    {"c": "fa-headphones", "l": "Headphones"},
    {"c": "fa-heart", "l": "Heart"},
    {"c": "fa-heart-o", "l": "Heart o"},
    {"c": "fa-heartbeat", "l": "Heartbeat"},
    {"c": "fa-history", "l": "History"},
    {"c": "fa-home", "l": "Home"},
    {"c": "fa-hospital-o", "l": "Hospital o"},
    {"c": "fa-hourglass", "l": "Hourglass"},
    {"c": "fa-hourglass-end", "l": "Hourglass end"},
    {"c": "fa-hourglass-half", "l": "Hourglass half"},
    {"c": "fa-hourglass-o", "l": "Hourglass o"},
    {"c": "fa-hourglass-start", "l": "Hourglass start"},
    {"c": "fa-houzz", "l": "Houzz"},
    {"c": "fa-html5", "l": "Html5"},
    {"c": "fa-i-cursor", "l": "I cursor"},
    {"c": "fa-ils", "l": "Ils"},
    {"c": "fa-inbox", "l": "Inbox"},
    {"c": "fa-indent", "l": "Indent"},
    {"c": "fa-industry", "l": "Industry"},
    {"c": "fa-info", "l": "Info"},
    {"c": "fa-info-circle", "l": "Info circle"},
    {"c": "fa-inr", "l": "Inr"},
    {"c": "fa-instagram", "l": "Instagram"},
    {"c": "fa-internet-explorer", "l": "Internet explorer"},
    {"c": "fa-ioxhost", "l": "Ioxhost"},
    {"c": "fa-italic", "l": "Italic"},
    {"c": "fa-joomla", "l": "Joomla"},
    {"c": "fa-jpy", "l": "Jpy"},
    {"c": "fa-jsfiddle", "l": "Jsfiddle"},
    {"c": "fa-key", "l": "Key"},
    {"c": "fa-keyboard-o", "l": "Keyboard o"},
    {"c": "fa-krw", "l": "Krw"},
    {"c": "fa-language", "l": "Language"},
    {"c": "fa-laptop", "l": "Laptop"},
    {"c": "fa-lastfm", "l": "Lastfm"},
    {"c": "fa-lastfm-square", "l": "Lastfm square"},
    {"c": "fa-leaf", "l": "Leaf"},
    {"c": "fa-leanpub", "l": "Leanpub"},
    {"c": "fa-lemon-o", "l": "Lemon o"},
    {"c": "fa-level-down", "l": "Level down"},
    {"c": "fa-level-up", "l": "Level up"},
    {"c": "fa-life-ring", "l": "Life ring"},
    {"c": "fa-lightbulb-o", "l": "Lightbulb o"},
    {"c": "fa-line-chart", "l": "Line chart"},
    {"c": "fa-link", "l": "Link"},
    {"c": "fa-linkedin", "l": "Linkedin"},
    {"c": "fa-linkedin-square", "l": "Linkedin square"},
    {"c": "fa-linux", "l": "Linux"},
    {"c": "fa-list", "l": "List"},
    {"c": "fa-list-alt", "l": "List alt"},
    {"c": "fa-list-ol", "l": "List ol"},
    {"c": "fa-list-ul", "l": "List ul"},
    {"c": "fa-location-arrow", "l": "Location arrow"},
    {"c": "fa-lock", "l": "Lock"},
    {"c": "fa-long-arrow-down", "l": "Long arrow down"},
    {"c": "fa-long-arrow-left", "l": "Long arrow left"},
    {"c": "fa-long-arrow-right", "l": "Long arrow right"},
    {"c": "fa-long-arrow-up", "l": "Long arrow up"},
    {"c": "fa-magic", "l": "Magic"},
    {"c": "fa-magnet", "l": "Magnet"},
    {"c": "fa-male", "l": "Male"},
    {"c": "fa-map", "l": "Map"},
    {"c": "fa-map-marker", "l": "Map marker"},
    {"c": "fa-map-o", "l": "Map o"},
    {"c": "fa-map-pin", "l": "Map pin"},
    {"c": "fa-map-signs", "l": "Map signs"},
    {"c": "fa-mars", "l": "Mars"},
    {"c": "fa-mars-double", "l": "Mars double"},
    {"c": "fa-mars-stroke", "l": "Mars stroke"},
    {"c": "fa-mars-stroke-h", "l": "Mars stroke h"},
    {"c": "fa-mars-stroke-v", "l": "Mars stroke v"},
    {"c": "fa-maxcdn", "l": "Maxcdn"},
    {"c": "fa-meanpath", "l": "Meanpath"},
    {"c": "fa-medium", "l": "Medium"},
    {"c": "fa-medkit", "l": "Medkit"},
    {"c": "fa-meh-o", "l": "Meh o"},
    {"c": "fa-mercury", "l": "Mercury"},
    {"c": "fa-microphone", "l": "Microphone"},
    {"c": "fa-microphone-slash", "l": "Microphone slash"},
    {"c": "fa-minus", "l": "Minus"},
    {"c": "fa-minus-circle", "l": "Minus circle"},
    {"c": "fa-minus-square", "l": "Minus square"},
    {"c": "fa-minus-square-o", "l": "Minus square o"},
    {"c": "fa-mobile", "l": "Mobile"},
    {"c": "fa-money", "l": "Money"},
    {"c": "fa-moon-o", "l": "Moon o"},
    {"c": "fa-motorcycle", "l": "Motorcycle"},
    {"c": "fa-mouse-pointer", "l": "Mouse pointer"},
    {"c": "fa-music", "l": "Music"},
    {"c": "fa-neuter", "l": "Neuter"},
    {"c": "fa-newspaper-o", "l": "Newspaper o"},
    {"c": "fa-object-group", "l": "Object group"},
    {"c": "fa-object-ungroup", "l": "Object ungroup"},
    {"c": "fa-odnoklassniki", "l": "Odnoklassniki"},
    {"c": "fa-odnoklassniki-square", "l": "Odnoklassniki square"},
    {"c": "fa-opencart", "l": "Opencart"},
    {"c": "fa-openid", "l": "Openid"},
    {"c": "fa-opera", "l": "Opera"},
    {"c": "fa-optin-monster", "l": "Optin monster"},
    {"c": "fa-outdent", "l": "Outdent"},
    {"c": "fa-pagelines", "l": "Pagelines"},
    {"c": "fa-paint-brush", "l": "Paint brush"},
    {"c": "fa-paper-plane", "l": "Paper plane"},
    {"c": "fa-paper-plane-o", "l": "Paper plane o"},
    {"c": "fa-paperclip", "l": "Paperclip"},
    {"c": "fa-paragraph", "l": "Paragraph"},
    {"c": "fa-pause", "l": "Pause"},
    {"c": "fa-paw", "l": "Paw"},
    {"c": "fa-paypal", "l": "Paypal"},
    {"c": "fa-pencil", "l": "Pencil"},
    {"c": "fa-pencil-square", "l": "Pencil square"},
    {"c": "fa-pencil-square-o", "l": "Pencil square o"},
    {"c": "fa-phone", "l": "Phone"},
    {"c": "fa-phone-square", "l": "Phone square"},
    {"c": "fa-picture-o", "l": "Picture o"},
    {"c": "fa-pie-chart", "l": "Pie chart"},
    {"c": "fa-pied-piper", "l": "Pied piper"},
    {"c": "fa-pied-piper-alt", "l": "Pied piper alt"},
    {"c": "fa-pinterest", "l": "Pinterest"},
    {"c": "fa-pinterest-p", "l": "Pinterest p"},
    {"c": "fa-pinterest-square", "l": "Pinterest square"},
    {"c": "fa-plane", "l": "Plane"},
    {"c": "fa-play", "l": "Play"},
    {"c": "fa-play-circle", "l": "Play circle"},
    {"c": "fa-play-circle-o", "l": "Play circle o"},
    {"c": "fa-plug", "l": "Plug"},
    {"c": "fa-plus", "l": "Plus"},
    {"c": "fa-plus-circle", "l": "Plus circle"},
    {"c": "fa-plus-square", "l": "Plus square"},
    {"c": "fa-plus-square-o", "l": "Plus square o"},
    {"c": "fa-power-off", "l": "Power off"},
    {"c": "fa-print", "l": "Print"},
    {"c": "fa-puzzle-piece", "l": "Puzzle piece"},
    {"c": "fa-qq", "l": "Qq"},
    {"c": "fa-qrcode", "l": "Qrcode"},
    {"c": "fa-question", "l": "Question"},
    {"c": "fa-question-circle", "l": "Question circle"},
    {"c": "fa-quote-left", "l": "Quote left"},
    {"c": "fa-quote-right", "l": "Quote right"},
    {"c": "fa-random", "l": "Random"},
    {"c": "fa-rebel", "l": "Rebel"},
    {"c": "fa-recycle", "l": "Recycle"},
    {"c": "fa-reddit", "l": "Reddit"},
    {"c": "fa-reddit-square", "l": "Reddit square"},
    {"c": "fa-refresh", "l": "Refresh"},
    {"c": "fa-registered", "l": "Registered"},
    {"c": "fa-renren", "l": "Renren"},
    {"c": "fa-repeat", "l": "Repeat"},
    {"c": "fa-reply", "l": "Reply"},
    {"c": "fa-reply-all", "l": "Reply all"},
    {"c": "fa-retweet", "l": "Retweet"},
    {"c": "fa-road", "l": "Road"},
    {"c": "fa-rocket", "l": "Rocket"},
    {"c": "fa-rss", "l": "Rss"},
    {"c": "fa-rss-square", "l": "Rss square"},
    {"c": "fa-rub", "l": "Rub"},
    {"c": "fa-safari", "l": "Safari"},
    {"c": "fa-scissors", "l": "Scissors"},
    {"c": "fa-search", "l": "Search"},
    {"c": "fa-search-minus", "l": "Search minus"},
    {"c": "fa-search-plus", "l": "Search plus"},
    {"c": "fa-sellsy", "l": "Sellsy"},
    {"c": "fa-server", "l": "Server"},
    {"c": "fa-share", "l": "Share"},
    {"c": "fa-share-alt", "l": "Share alt"},
    {"c": "fa-share-alt-square", "l": "Share alt square"},
    {"c": "fa-share-square", "l": "Share square"},
    {"c": "fa-share-square-o", "l": "Share square o"},
    {"c": "fa-shield", "l": "Shield"},
    {"c": "fa-ship", "l": "Ship"},
    {"c": "fa-shirtsinbulk", "l": "Shirtsinbulk"},
    {"c": "fa-shopping-cart", "l": "Shopping cart"},
    {"c": "fa-sign-in", "l": "Sign in"},
    {"c": "fa-sign-out", "l": "Sign out"},
    {"c": "fa-signal", "l": "Signal"},
    {"c": "fa-simplybuilt", "l": "Simplybuilt"},
    {"c": "fa-sitemap", "l": "Sitemap"},
    {"c": "fa-skyatlas", "l": "Skyatlas"},
    {"c": "fa-skype", "l": "Skype"},
    {"c": "fa-slack", "l": "Slack"},
    {"c": "fa-sliders", "l": "Sliders"},
    {"c": "fa-slideshare", "l": "Slideshare"},
    {"c": "fa-smile-o", "l": "Smile o"},
    {"c": "fa-sort", "l": "Sort"},
    {"c": "fa-sort-alpha-asc", "l": "Sort alpha asc"},
    {"c": "fa-sort-alpha-desc", "l": "Sort alpha desc"},
    {"c": "fa-sort-amount-asc", "l": "Sort amount asc"},
    {"c": "fa-sort-amount-desc", "l": "Sort amount desc"},
    {"c": "fa-sort-asc", "l": "Sort asc"},
    {"c": "fa-sort-desc", "l": "Sort desc"},
    {"c": "fa-sort-numeric-asc", "l": "Sort numeric asc"},
    {"c": "fa-sort-numeric-desc", "l": "Sort numeric desc"},
    {"c": "fa-soundcloud", "l": "Soundcloud"},
    {"c": "fa-space-shuttle", "l": "Space shuttle"},
    {"c": "fa-spinner", "l": "Spinner"},
    {"c": "fa-spoon", "l": "Spoon"},
    {"c": "fa-spotify", "l": "Spotify"},
    {"c": "fa-square", "l": "Square"},
    {"c": "fa-square-o", "l": "Square o"},
    {"c": "fa-stack-exchange", "l": "Stack exchange"},
    {"c": "fa-stack-overflow", "l": "Stack overflow"},
    {"c": "fa-star", "l": "Star"},
    {"c": "fa-star-half", "l": "Star half"},
    {"c": "fa-star-half-o", "l": "Star half o"},
    {"c": "fa-star-o", "l": "Star o"},
    {"c": "fa-steam", "l": "Steam"},
    {"c": "fa-steam-square", "l": "Steam square"},
    {"c": "fa-step-backward", "l": "Step backward"},
    {"c": "fa-step-forward", "l": "Step forward"},
    {"c": "fa-stethoscope", "l": "Stethoscope"},
    {"c": "fa-sticky-note", "l": "Sticky note"},
    {"c": "fa-sticky-note-o", "l": "Sticky note o"},
    {"c": "fa-stop", "l": "Stop"},
    {"c": "fa-street-view", "l": "Street view"},
    {"c": "fa-strikethrough", "l": "Strikethrough"},
    {"c": "fa-stumbleupon", "l": "Stumbleupon"},
    {"c": "fa-stumbleupon-circle", "l": "Stumbleupon circle"},
    {"c": "fa-subscript", "l": "Subscript"},
    {"c": "fa-subway", "l": "Subway"},
    {"c": "fa-suitcase", "l": "Suitcase"},
    {"c": "fa-sun-o", "l": "Sun o"},
    {"c": "fa-superscript", "l": "Superscript"},
    {"c": "fa-table", "l": "Table"},
    {"c": "fa-tablet", "l": "Tablet"},
    {"c": "fa-tachometer", "l": "Tachometer"},
    {"c": "fa-tag", "l": "Tag"},
    {"c": "fa-tags", "l": "Tags"},
    {"c": "fa-tasks", "l": "Tasks"},
    {"c": "fa-taxi", "l": "Taxi"},
    {"c": "fa-television", "l": "Television"},
    {"c": "fa-tencent-weibo", "l": "Tencent weibo"},
    {"c": "fa-terminal", "l": "Terminal"},
    {"c": "fa-text-height", "l": "Text height"},
    {"c": "fa-text-width", "l": "Text width"},
    {"c": "fa-th", "l": "Th"},
    {"c": "fa-th-large", "l": "Th large"},
    {"c": "fa-th-list", "l": "Th list"},
    {"c": "fa-thumb-tack", "l": "Thumb tack"},
    {"c": "fa-thumbs-down", "l": "Thumbs down"},
    {"c": "fa-thumbs-o-down", "l": "Thumbs o down"},
    {"c": "fa-thumbs-o-up", "l": "Thumbs o up"},
    {"c": "fa-thumbs-up", "l": "Thumbs up"},
    {"c": "fa-ticket", "l": "Ticket"},
    {"c": "fa-times", "l": "Times"},
    {"c": "fa-times-circle", "l": "Times circle"},
    {"c": "fa-times-circle-o", "l": "Times circle o"},
    {"c": "fa-tint", "l": "Tint"},
    {"c": "fa-toggle-off", "l": "Toggle off"},
    {"c": "fa-toggle-on", "l": "Toggle on"},
    {"c": "fa-trademark", "l": "Trademark"},
    {"c": "fa-train", "l": "Train"},
    {"c": "fa-transgender", "l": "Transgender"},
    {"c": "fa-transgender-alt", "l": "Transgender alt"},
    {"c": "fa-trash", "l": "Trash"},
    {"c": "fa-trash-o", "l": "Trash o"},
    {"c": "fa-tree", "l": "Tree"},
    {"c": "fa-trello", "l": "Trello"},
    {"c": "fa-tripadvisor", "l": "Tripadvisor"},
    {"c": "fa-trophy", "l": "Trophy"},
    {"c": "fa-truck", "l": "Truck"},
    {"c": "fa-try", "l": "Try"},
    {"c": "fa-tty", "l": "Tty"},
    {"c": "fa-tumblr", "l": "Tumblr"},
    {"c": "fa-tumblr-square", "l": "Tumblr square"},
    {"c": "fa-twitch", "l": "Twitch"},
    {"c": "fa-twitter", "l": "Twitter"},
    {"c": "fa-twitter-square", "l": "Twitter square"},
    {"c": "fa-umbrella", "l": "Umbrella"},
    {"c": "fa-underline", "l": "Underline"},
    {"c": "fa-undo", "l": "Undo"},
    {"c": "fa-university", "l": "University"},
    {"c": "fa-unlock", "l": "Unlock"},
    {"c": "fa-unlock-alt", "l": "Unlock alt"},
    {"c": "fa-upload", "l": "Upload"},
    {"c": "fa-usd", "l": "Usd"},
    {"c": "fa-user", "l": "User"},
    {"c": "fa-user-md", "l": "User md"},
    {"c": "fa-user-plus", "l": "User plus"},
    {"c": "fa-user-secret", "l": "User secret"},
    {"c": "fa-user-times", "l": "User times"},
    {"c": "fa-users", "l": "Users"},
    {"c": "fa-venus", "l": "Venus"},
    {"c": "fa-venus-double", "l": "Venus double"},
    {"c": "fa-venus-mars", "l": "Venus mars"},
    {"c": "fa-viacoin", "l": "Viacoin"},
    {"c": "fa-video-camera", "l": "Video camera"},
    {"c": "fa-vimeo", "l": "Vimeo"},
    {"c": "fa-vimeo-square", "l": "Vimeo square"},
    {"c": "fa-vine", "l": "Vine"},
    {"c": "fa-vk", "l": "Vk"},
    {"c": "fa-volume-down", "l": "Volume down"},
    {"c": "fa-volume-off", "l": "Volume off"},
    {"c": "fa-volume-up", "l": "Volume up"},
    {"c": "fa-weibo", "l": "Weibo"},
    {"c": "fa-weixin", "l": "Weixin"},
    {"c": "fa-whatsapp", "l": "Whatsapp"},
    {"c": "fa-wheelchair", "l": "Wheelchair"},
    {"c": "fa-wifi", "l": "Wifi"},
    {"c": "fa-wikipedia-w", "l": "Wikipedia w"},
    {"c": "fa-windows", "l": "Windows"},
    {"c": "fa-wordpress", "l": "Wordpress"},
    {"c": "fa-wrench", "l": "Wrench"},
    {"c": "fa-xing", "l": "Xing"},
    {"c": "fa-xing-square", "l": "Xing square"},
    {"c": "fa-y-combinator", "l": "Y combinator"},
    {"c": "fa-yahoo", "l": "Yahoo"},
    {"c": "fa-yelp", "l": "Yelp"},
    {"c": "fa-youtube", "l": "Youtube"},
    {"c": "fa-youtube-play", "l": "Youtube play"},
    {"c": "fa-youtube-square", "l": "Youtube square"}
]
```

Comment: "l" for label, "c" for className - Stack had a character max on the response...

Answer (score 2):

Here is a JSON file with `name:entity` format:

[font-awesome.json](https://gist.github.com/jabney/7720a6f92e53a830578c)
(~15K).

This is the python module used to generate the JSON:

[gen_fontawesome.py](https://gist.github.com/jabney/8b395c983b70157e6492)

It reads the names and entity refs directly from the [Font Awesome Cheatsheet](http://fortawesome.github.io/Font-Awesome/cheatsheet/) on the website which makes it easy to keep them updated.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a pretty hacky custom solution, using C# and the 3.2.1 version of FontAwesome. I took [this sample CSS scraper](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/rahul4_saxena/reading-and-parsing-a-css-file-in-Asp-Net/) from [Rahul Saxena](http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/authors/rahul4_saxena/rahul-saxena.aspx) and customized it for FontAwesome specifically; you just feed in the app path to the css file.  I hope this helps somebody:

```
public List<string> ParseCssFile(string cssFilePath)
{
     string aa = null;
     string content = CleanCssFile(File.ReadAllText(cssFilePath));
     string[] parts = content.Split('}');
     for (int i = 0; i < parts.Length; i++)
     {
          if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(parts[i]))
          {
               string[] parts1 = parts[i].Split('{');
               string str = parts1[0].ToString().Remove(0, 1);
               aa = string.Concat(aa, str, ",");
           }
     }
     int len = aa.LastIndexOf(',');
     string ss = aa.Remove(len);
     string ss1 = aa.Remove(len - 1);
     List<string> parts2 = ss.Split(',').ToList();            

     return parts2.Where(x => x.StartsWith("icon-") && !x.Contains('.'))
           .Select(x => x.Replace(":before", string.Empty).Trim())
           .Where(x => !x.Contains(' '))
           .Distinct()
           .ToList();
}

private string CleanCssFile(string rawText)
{
     string reg = "(/\\*(.|[\r\n])*?\\*/)|(//.*)";
     Regex r = new Regex(reg);
     rawText = r.Replace(rawText, "");
     rawText = rawText.Replace("\r", "").Replace("\n", "");
     return rawText;
}
```

Comment: Nice. Here is mine: https://github.com/fzany/Font-Awesome-Cheat-Charp